# Uncaught ReferenceError : json is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, api

Not sure why it's saying json isn't defined in my API call below:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    function day(time) {
        jQuery.parseJSON(time);
    }

    $.getJSON("http://www.freecodecamp.com/news/hot", function(news) {
        var html = "";
        var br = "<div class='br'></div>";

        json.forEach(function(val) {
            html += "<div class='col-md-3'>"

            html += "<div class = 'panel panel-default'>"

            html += "<div class = 'panel-image'>"

            html += "<img src='" + val.image + "  " + "'width='100%' />"

            html += "</div>"

            html += br

            html += "<a href='" + val.link + " > " + val.headline + "</a>"

            html += br

            html += "<p>♥" + " " + val.upVotes.length() + "</p>"

            html += br

            html += "<p>" + " " + "Posted on: " + day(val.timePosted) + "</p>"

            html += "</div>"

            html += "</div>"

        });

        $(".stories").html(html);
    });
});
```

Been trying to change it, it still returns the error if I do Json or JSON from what I see the capitalization doesn't matter it always returns a ref error.

Comment: Well, you didn't define `json`. Maybe you want `news.forEach` ?

Answer (score 0):

you have to use news instead of json.

```
news.forEach(function(val) {
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no `json` name variable you have use `news` as `function(news){` in function you are getting news.

```
$.getJSON("http://www.freecodecamp.com/news/hot", function(news){
var html = "";
var br = "<div class='br'></div>";

news.forEach(function(val) {
       .
       .
```